# Reverse strings in a text file using command-line tools like AWK or SED

Tags: windows, text, command-line, awk, reverse

I have a text file containing lines like

```
ABCD
1234
bear
Anders Ångström
```

And I need to transform it into

```
DBCA
4321
raeb
mörtsgnÅ srednA
```

I need to do this in command line, so I think AWK is the best tool for the job, but I might be wrong. Maybe it's possible to do it with Regex replace? Notepad2 knows Regex replace.

Later edit: I need do do it in Windows (I'm using GNUWin32 tools) and I need it to work with Unicode characters like Å, ö, ë, Ş, Ĕ, etc.

Comment: Problem with Unicode characters like `Å` is that its not one character, its group of code to represent one character. `ï¿½`.  This way it would be wrong to reverse it as a group. I am not sure if you ever find a good solution for that.  Why do you need to reverse it?

Answer (score 5):

Use `rev` command like below.

```
$ rev < file
DCBA
4321
raeb
```

Comment: ooh!.. saw this just now..same as my answer!

Comment: I can't find the rev utility in Windows or in the GNUWin32 packages. Where can I get a Windows version of the utility?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with rev command:

```
rev File
```

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
ABCD
1234
bear
AMD$ rev File
DCBA
4321
raeb


man rev : 
The rev utility copies the specified files to the standard output,
reversing the order of characters in every line.  If no files are speci-
fied, the standard input is read.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -vFS= '{do printf $(NF);while(--NF>0);print ""}' file
DCBA
4321
raeb
```

Or like this:

```
awk -vFS= '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf $(i);print ""}' file
DCBA
4321
raeb
```

For most correct use of `printf`, change it from `printf $(i)` to `printf "%s",$(i)`

Comment: The second solution works OK if there are no Unicode characters like "Ë" for example. Note: being in Windows I had to escape quotes (\"). The first solution gives me an eror: "gawk: (FILENAME=in.txt FNR=4) fatal: NF set to negative value - when the file has empty lines

Comment: @BearBear You should have posted that this was on windows and that you have Unicode characters form the start.  As you see know, nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Sed solution, here it is:

```
+$ sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' <<EOF
+> ABCD
+> 1234
+> bear
+> EOF
DCBA
4321
raeb
```

You may find more write-only programs in Sed at http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt.

Comment: Thanks, it is slow but it works OK if there are no Unicode characters like "Ĕ" or "Ş" in the input text file.

Comment: @BearBear Hmm. It work OK with any characters, actually. You’d better check your locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rev command.

```
rev < filename > output filename
```

Output will be stored in the file. If you are not giving that it will be printed in stdout

Answer (score 0):

This `perl` may do.
But not sure if you have `perl` for windows.  If not, copy file to a linux server, convert it.

```
perl -ne 'chomp;print scalar reverse . "\n";' file
DCBA
4321
raeb
mörtsgnÅ srednA
```

---

This bash script do also work in linux

```
cat convert
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
for (( i=${#input}-1; i>=0; i-- ));do
        reverse="$reverse${input:$i:1}"
done
echo "$reverse"
```

```
./convert Ångström
mörtsgnÅ
```